# Mapping network drive using WNetAddConnection2 from "Run As Administrator" process does not work

Tags: c#, winapi, runas, mapped-drive

I have an application which calls `WNetAddConnection2` to map a network drive. This works perfectly unless I run the application as Administrator (right click - Run As Administrator) in which case the function returns 0 (success) but the mapped drive does not appear.

What seems to be happening here is that there are two *Contexts*, the Admin one in which my program is running and the user one in which windows explorer is running and I am looking for the mapped drive. I think the drive mapping is succeeding the in *"Admin Context"* but is not visible in the *"User context"*.

When I'm running as administrator `Environment.GetLogicalDrives()` includes the drive letter I tried to map, making me think the mapping succeeded in the *"Admin Context"*.

Apologies if I have totally got the wrong idea with multiple contexts, but it seems like the best explanation for what I am seeing.

There are two potential answers to this question:

1) How do I map a drive so it is visible in all contexts?

2) How do I execute something (process / thread / API call) from a "Run as Administrator" process without Admin rights (i.e. within the *"User Context"*)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767614/

Answer (score 1):

1) drive will be visible only in logon session with *LUID* same as your token [`TOKEN_STATISTICS.AuthenticationId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379632(v=vs.85).aspx)

will be created Symbolic link object under *`\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<LogonId>\<X>:`* to *`\Device\LanmamRedirector\;<X>:<LogonId>\server\share`*  as result drive `<X>:` will be visible only for processes running in *`<LogonId>`* session. and processes running "As Admin" have different *`<LogonId>`* compare processes run not "As Admin"

2) you need impersonate another context before call `NetUseAdd` or `WNetAddConnection2`.

for example you can enumerate processes, found explorer which have same terminal `SessionId` (not confuse with logon sessions) and impersonate it (open it token, duplicate and impersonate) . or more general open every process token in same terminal session as your process, query it token `TokenElevationType` ([`TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530718(v=vs.85).aspx)) and if it `TokenElevationTypeLimited` - duplicate and impersonate this token, before call `NetUseAdd`

---

> How do I execute something (process / thread / API call) from a "Run
>   as Administrator" process without Admin rights (i.e. within the "User
>   Context")?

example of working code:

```
#include <TlHelp32.h>

#define BOOL_TO_ERR(b) ((b) ? NOERROR : GetLastError())

ULONG RunNonElevated(PCWSTR lpApplicationName, PWSTR lpCommandLine)
{
    HANDLE hToken;

    ULONG err = BOOL_TO_ERR(OpenProcessToken(NtCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken));

    if (err != NOERROR)
    {
        return err;
    }

    DWORD cb, rcb;

    union {
        TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE tet;
        TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN tlt;
    };

    TOKEN_STATISTICS ts;
    LUID AuthenticationId = {};

    BOOL bSearchToken = FALSE, bFound = FALSE;

    err = BOOL_TO_ERR(GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenElevationType, &tet, sizeof(tet), &rcb));

    if (err == NOERROR)
    {
        if (tet == TokenElevationTypeFull)
        {
            err = BOOL_TO_ERR(GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenLinkedToken, &tlt, sizeof(tlt), &rcb));

            if (err == NOERROR)
            {
                err = BOOL_TO_ERR(GetTokenInformation(tlt.LinkedToken, TokenStatistics, &ts, sizeof(ts), &rcb));

                CloseHandle(tlt.LinkedToken);

                if (bSearchToken = (err == NOERROR))
                {
                    AuthenticationId.LowPart = ts.AuthenticationId.LowPart;
                    AuthenticationId.HighPart = ts.AuthenticationId.HighPart;

                    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = {
                        1, { { { SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE } , SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED } }
                    };

                    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hToken);

    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof (si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if (bSearchToken)
    {
        HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

        if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            PROCESSENTRY32W pe = { sizeof(pe) };

            static volatile UCHAR guz;

            PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

            cb = 0, rcb = FIELD_OFFSET(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES, Privileges[SE_MAX_WELL_KNOWN_PRIVILEGE]);

            union {
                PVOID buf;
                PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES ptp;
            };

            BOOL fHavePrivs = FALSE;

            if (Process32FirstW(hSnapshot, &pe))
            {
                do 
                {
                    if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe.th32ProcessID))
                    {
                        if (OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hToken))
                        {

                            if (!fHavePrivs) do 
                            {
                                if (cb < rcb)
                                {
                                    cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                                }

                                if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, buf, cb, &rcb))
                                {
                                    if (ULONG PrivilegeCount = ptp->PrivilegeCount)
                                    {
                                        int n = 3;
                                        BOOL fAdjust = FALSE;

                                        PLUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges = ptp->Privileges;
                                        do 
                                        {
                                            switch (Privileges->Luid.LowPart)
                                            {
                                            case SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE:
                                            case SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_PRIVILEGE:
                                            case SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE:
                                                if (!(Privileges->Attributes & SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED))
                                                {
                                                    Privileges->Attributes |= SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
                                                    fAdjust = TRUE;
                                                }

                                                if (!--n)
                                                {
                                                    if (DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, 
                                                        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, 
                                                        0, SecurityImpersonation, TokenImpersonation, 
                                                        &tlt.LinkedToken))
                                                    {
                                                        if (fAdjust)
                                                        {
                                                            AdjustTokenPrivileges(tlt.LinkedToken, FALSE, ptp, rcb, NULL, NULL);
                                                        }
                                                        fHavePrivs = SetThreadToken(0, tlt.LinkedToken);
                                                        CloseHandle(tlt.LinkedToken);
                                                    }
                                                    goto __1;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } while (Privileges++, --PrivilegeCount);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }

                            } while (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);

__1:
                            if (fHavePrivs &&
                                GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenStatistics, &ts, sizeof(ts), &rcb) &&
                                ts.AuthenticationId.LowPart == AuthenticationId.LowPart &&
                                ts.AuthenticationId.HighPart == AuthenticationId.HighPart)
                            {
                                bFound = DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, 
                                    TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE|TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY, 
                                    0, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &tlt.LinkedToken);
                            }
                            CloseHandle(hToken);
                        }
                        CloseHandle(hProcess);
                    }
                } while (!bFound && Process32NextW(hSnapshot, &pe));
            }
            CloseHandle(hSnapshot);

            if (bFound)
            {
                err = BOOL_TO_ERR(CreateProcessAsUserW(tlt.LinkedToken, lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, 
                    NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi));

                CloseHandle(tlt.LinkedToken);

                if (err == NOERROR)
                {
                    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (err == NOERROR)
    {
        if ((err = BOOL_TO_ERR(CreateProcessW(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine,
            NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))) == NOERROR)
        {
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        }
    }

    return err;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code example of what you mentioned in (2)?

Comment: @trungdinhtrong - i paste code for (2) - however if your process token not `TokenElevationTypeFull` type - this mean you run not elevated (`TokenElevationTypeLimited` case) or as Built-in Admin or UAC if off (`TokenElevationTypeDefault` case) - in this case no sense exec additional process

Comment: Thanks a lot, RbMm.

Comment: As you might guess, my primary problem is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42767614/how-to-correctly-detect-network-drive-when-running-with-elevated-privileges/42772840#42772840. So I will definitely test that solution. My apology if I will not come into confirming this solution here. But your code posting is definitely very useful. And I really appreciate you taking times and effort to help out. Code example around this area is so hard to find.

Comment: @trungdinhtrong - how i discover - for get drives mask - you not need launch process - enough only impersonate - i paste code under your question. this is much more simply